# How can I prove $P(h(X)\geq a)\geq\frac{E(h(X))-a}{\alpha-a}$?

Tags: probability-theory

This is an exercise from Jacod's *[Probability Essentials](http://books.google.com/books?id=OK_d-w18EVgC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)*:
[image]

Putting everything into integration one can get:

$$
\int_{\Omega}(\alpha-a)1_{A}dP\geq \int_{\Omega}[h(X)-a]dP \tag{*}
$$
where $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ is the underlying probability space and 
$$
A:=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid h(X(\omega))\geq a\}.
$$
If $h$ is bounded by $\alpha$, then things can be done by (*). <s>Any idea how I can go on?</s>

---

[Remark] I didn't notice that $[0,\alpha]$ is the range of $h$ and thus $h$ is bounded by $\alpha$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prove the pointwise inequality $
h(X)-a\leqslant(\alpha-a)\cdot\mathbf 1_A$ and integrate it with respect to $\mathrm P$. The LHS yields $\mathrm E(h(X))-a$ and the RHS yields $(\alpha-a)\cdot\mathrm P(A)$. This is the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$E[h(X)]-a=\int_{\Omega}(h(\omega)-a)dP(\omega)=\int_A(h(\omega)-a)dP(\omega)+\int_{A^c}(h(\omega)-a)dP(\omega).$$
On $A$, we have $h(\omega)-a\leq \alpha-a$ and on $A^c$ we have $h(\omega)-\alpha\leq 0$ hence 
$$E[h(X)]-a\leq \int_A(h(\omega)-a)dP(\omega)=(\alpha-a)P(A),$$
what is wanted.